# How do I force an img element to take the width and height of its parent?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to allow an image to take the height and width of its parent.
Its parent is a grid item(div1) that has a height 100% of the container.

What I've expected and wanted:

1. div1 will take the height of the parent(container) means div1 height should be 500px and a width of 50% of the container.
2. The image should take the width and height of its parent(div1). Image should have a height of 500px and width 100% of its parent.

What the result shows:

1. image took a height of 530px and the div1 took a height of 530px too.

I'm confused with this behavior. What I might be doing wrong?

My code:

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.container .div1 {
  height: 100%;
}

.container .div1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h1>heading</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand why div1 takes on the height of the img (this can be tested by setting a background color on div1 and setting opacity 0 on the img), but the img itself is overflowing in some sense. Is the combination of grid, 100% height and cover confused in some way.

For now a partial way forward may be to not allow them to overflow. This snippet sets overflow hidden on div1.

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.container .div1 {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .div1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h1>heading</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

This snippet puts a background color on the container and changes the object-fit to contain, just to demonstrate that the object fit and overflow hidden are being invoked.

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.container .div1 {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .div1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
.container {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h1>heading</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use display flex? width: 100%; height: 50%; and if it doesn't work then you use !important like this width: 100% !important;

Comment: In my case it's preferable to use grid. I tried !important it didn't work.